# async/await not working within Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an Intersection Observer on my website that watches for a specific element to come into the viewport and then cycles through multiple classList.add() and classList.remove() methods, adding and removing various animate.css animation classes. I have the whole Intersection Observer working, except that the async/await keywords don't seem to have any effect, so all the timers start as soon as the Intersection Observer is triggered. This prevents me from being able to stop the animation sequence when the element scrolls out of view or when one of three inputs within the contact form are active.

My current workaround is to set the setTimout() delays to increasing intervals, so they play in the correct sequence, however that does not address the inability to stop the animation sequence.

I've read through a lot of MDN documentation, but I can't figure out if I'm using async/await incorrectly or if it's just not possible to use async/await within an Intersection Observer.

My Intersection Observer and its associated code are as follows:

```
const contactSectionSubmitButtonWrapper = document.querySelector('.submit-button-wrapper');

async function timer(fn, milliseconds){
  await setTimeout(fn, milliseconds);
}

async function animation01(){
  if(document.activeElement.id == ("name-field" || "email-field" || "message-field")) {
    console.log('Submit button animation stopped because an input field is active.');
  } else {
    console.log('Submit button animation 01');
    contactSectionSubmitButtonWrapper.classList.add('animate__pulse');
  }
}

// There are twelve more of these animationXX functions,
// but it's the same basic concept repeated, so I omitted
// the other twelve for the sake of brevity.

const contactSectionSubmitButtonObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
  async(entries)=>{
    console.log(entries);
    for (const entry of entries) {
      if(entry.isIntersecting) {
        await timer(animation01, 3000);
        await timer(animation02, 6000);
        await timer(animation03, 9000);
        await timer(animation04, 12000);
        await timer(animation05, 15000);
        await timer(animation06, 18000);
        await timer(animation07, 21000);
        await timer(animation08, 24000);
        await timer(animation09, 27000);
        await timer(animation10, 30000);
        await timer(animation11, 31000);
        await timer(animation12, 35000);
        await timer(animation13, 38000);
      }
    }
  },
  {
    threshold: 0.1,
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px'
  }
);

contactSectionSubmitButtonObserver.observe(contactSectionSubmitButtonWrapper);
```

Comment: it's the `await setTimeout(fn, milliseconds);` that does not do what you think it does, as `setTimeout` does NOT return a Promise to `await` - you probably want `async function timer(fn, milliseconds) {
 await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
 fn();
}`
instead

Comment: It would pobably be a lot cleaner to set up your animations with the Web Animation API. Also beware, you don't stop your observer and the next callback won't await the previous one. You may very well have many of these callbacks conflicting with each others

Answer (score 1):

The major miss here is that `setTimeout` is not a async function. So we can await it.

Modify the `timer` function as below:

```
async function timer(fn, milliseconds){
   return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(()=> {
        resolve(fn())
      }, milliseconds)
    });
}
```

An example of something you may trying to achieve:

```js
async function timer(fn, milliseconds){
   return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(()=> {
        resolve(fn())
      }, milliseconds)
    });
}

const entries = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
const driver = async ()=>{
  for (const entry of entries) {
    await timer(()=> console.log(entry), 1000);
  }
}

driver();
```